# Entitlements invalid?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios5, entitlements, xcode4.4

I'm currently running on the Developer Preview of Xcode. And I noticed that there are is a generated "entitlements" file. Whenever I build my iOS app I get this error:

> The executable was signed with invalid entitlements.

Why am I getting this? I'm assuming that it is because that generated entitlements file. I've also looked at other similar questions and they all are talking about Ad hoc distribution, which I am NOT doing.

Anyone run across this problem before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up just disabling entitlements in the Project settings.